# Migrate processing scripts from QGIS 2 to QGIS 3 (Merge Adjacent lines)

Tags: pyqgis, merge

I am having trouble with a script.

The last script here in this link is working on QGIS 2.x and I tried to modify it to use it in QGIS 3.x but I can't till now

[Merging adjacent lines in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/228267/merging-adjacent-lines-in-qgis)

I am trying till this moment
this is the script in QGIS v2

```
##Lines=vector line

from qgis.core import *
import processing
def find_adjacent(selected_ids): # for finding adjacent features
    outlist = []
    outinds = []
    outset = set()                                  
    for j, l in enumerate(selected_ids):            
        as_set = set(l)                             
        inds = []               
        for k in outset.copy():
            if outlist[k] & as_set:
                outset.remove(k)
                as_set |= outlist[k]            
                                                
                inds.extend(outinds[k])
        outset.add(j)                   
        outlist.append(as_set)          
        outinds.append(inds + [j])      
    outinds = [outinds[j] for j in outset]      
    del outset, outlist 
    result = [[selected_ids[j] for j in k] for k in outinds]    
    return result   

layer = processing.getObject(Lines)     #get input layer from GUI
crs = layer.crs().toWkt()

# Create the output layer
outLayer = QgsVectorLayer('Linestring?crs='+ crs, 'snapped' , 'memory')
prov = outLayer.dataProvider()
fields = layer.pendingFields()
prov.addAttributes(fields)
outLayer.updateFields()

already_processed = []
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
    attrs = feat.attributes()
    geom = feat.geometry()
    curr_id = feat["id"]
    if curr_id not in already_processed:
        query = '"id" = %s' % (curr_id)
        selection = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
        selected_ids = [k.geometry().asPolyline() for k in selection]       
        feedback.pushInfo("selected_ids")
        feedback.pushInfo(str(selected_ids))
        adjacent_feats = find_adjacent(selected_ids)
        feedback.pushInfo("adjacent_feats")
        feedback.pushInfo(str(adjacent_feats))
        for f in adjacent_feats:
            first = True
            for x in xrange(0, len(f)):
                geom = (QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(w) for w in f[x]]))
                if first:
                    outFeat = QgsFeature()
                    outFeat.setGeometry(geom)
                    outGeom = outFeat.geometry()
                    first = False
                else:
                    outGeom = outGeom.combine(geom)
            outFeat.setAttributes(attrs)
            outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)
            prov.addFeatures([outFeat])
        already_processed.append(curr_id)
    else:
        continue

# Add the layer to the Layers panel
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(outLayer)
```

and this is my attempt to modify the code in QGIS 3.x

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                       QgsFeatureSink,
                       QgsProcessingException,
                       QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                       QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                       QgsFeature,
                       QgsFeatureRequest,
                       QgsGeometry,
                       QgsPoint,
                       QgsProject
                       )
import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):
    INPUT = 'INPUT'
    OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'
    def tr(self, string):
        return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)
    def createInstance(self):
        return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()
    def name(self):
        return 'myscript'
    def displayName(self):
        return self.tr('My Script')
    def group(self):
        return self.tr('Example scripts')
    def groupId(self):   
        return 'examplescripts'
    def shortHelpString(self):
        return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")
    def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT,
                self.tr('Input layer'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorAnyGeometry]
            )
        )
        self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
                self.OUTPUT,
                self.tr('Output layer')
            )
        )

    def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
        """
        Here is where the processing itself takes place.
        """
        source = self.parameterAsSource(
            parameters,
            self.INPUT,
            context
        )

    
        if source is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

        (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
            parameters,
            self.OUTPUT,
            context,
            source.fields(),
            source.wkbType(),
            source.sourceCrs()
        )

        if sink is None:
            raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))



        def find_adjacent(selected_ids): # for finding adjacent features
            outlist = []
            outinds = []
            outset = set()                                  
            for j, l in enumerate(selected_ids):           
                as_set = set(l)                            
                inds = []               
                for k in outset.copy():
                    if outlist[k] & as_set:
                        outset.remove(k)
                        as_set |= outlist[k]            
                                                       
                        inds.extend(outinds[k])
                outset.add(j)                   #1st iteration outset = {0}
                outlist.append(as_set)          #1st iteration outlist = { l }
                outinds.append(inds + [j])      #1st iteration outinds = [0]
            outinds = [outinds[j] for j in outset]      
            del outset, outlist 
            result = [[selected_ids[j] for j in k] for k in outinds]    
            return result   
        # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
        # get features from source
        total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
        features = source.getFeatures()
        already_processed = []
        for current, feature in enumerate(features):
            # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
            if feedback.isCanceled():
                break

            attrs = feature.attributes()
            geom = feature.geometry()
            curr_id = feature["strahler"]
            if curr_id not in already_processed:
                query = '"strahler" = %s' % (curr_id)
                selection = source.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
                selected_ids = [k.geometry().asMultiPolyline() for k in selection]      #here I tried asPolyline as the QGIS v2 but it tells me "TypeError: MultiLineString geometry cannot be converted to a polyline. Only single line or curve types are permitted." so I made it as MultiPolyline 
                #feedback.pushInfo(str(selected_ids))
                adjacent_feats = find_adjacent(selected_ids[0][0])
                feedback.pushInfo(str(adjacent_feats))
                for f in adjacent_feats:
                    first = True
                    for x in range(0, len(f)):
                        geom = (QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(w) for w in f[x]])) 
                        if first:
                            outFeat = QgsFeature()
                            outFeat.setGeometry(geom)
                            outGeom = outFeat.geometry()
                            first = False
                        else:
                            outGeom = outGeom.combine(geom)
                    outFeat.setAttributes(attrs)
                    outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)
                    sink.addFeatures([outFeat])
                already_processed.append(curr_id)
            else:
                continue

        # Add the layer to the Layers panel
        return {self.OUTPUT: sink}
```

the output of this code is merging all features that had the common feature in one feature not the adjacent ones ---> because of asMultiPolyline

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/371779/edit) and include your QGIS 3 attempt and any exceptions (as text, not screenshots).

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I did it Wowww!!
After many attempts and using the awesome line to debugging in pyQgis feedback.pushInfo() that helped me a lot to understand the logic, I succeeded

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
from qgis.core import (QgsProcessing,
                      QgsFeatureSink,
                      QgsProcessingException,
                      QgsProcessingAlgorithm,
                      QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource,
                      QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink,
                      QgsFeature,
                      QgsFeatureRequest,
                      QgsGeometry,
                      QgsPoint,
                      QgsProject
                      )
import processing


class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):


   INPUT = 'INPUT'
   OUTPUT = 'OUTPUT'

   def tr(self, string):
      
       return QCoreApplication.translate('Processing', string)

   def createInstance(self):
       return ExampleProcessingAlgorithm()

   def name(self):
   
       return 'myscript'

   def displayName(self):
    
   
       return self.tr('My Script')

   def group(self):
    
       return self.tr('Example scripts')

   def groupId(self):
      
       return 'examplescripts'

   def shortHelpString(self):
    
       return self.tr("Example algorithm short description")

   def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
     
       self.addParameter(
           QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
               self.INPUT,
               self.tr('Input layer'),
               [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorLine]
           )
       )

      
       self.addParameter(
           QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSink(
               self.OUTPUT,
               self.tr('Output layer')
           )
       )

   def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
     
       source = self.parameterAsSource(
           parameters,
           self.INPUT,
           context
       )

      
       if source is None:
           raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSourceError(parameters, self.INPUT))

       (sink, dest_id) = self.parameterAsSink(
           parameters,
           self.OUTPUT,
           context,
           source.fields(),
           source.wkbType(),
           source.sourceCrs()
       )

       # Send some information to the user
       feedback.pushInfo('CRS is {}'.format(source.sourceCrs().authid()))

      
       if sink is None:
           raise QgsProcessingException(self.invalidSinkError(parameters, self.OUTPUT))



       def find_adjacent(selected_ids): # for finding adjacent features
           outlist = []
           outinds = []
           outset = set()                                  #create new empty set object
           #feedback.pushInfo("selected Ids before enumerate----------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(selected_ids))
           for j, l in enumerate(selected_ids):
               #feedback.pushInfo("j ---------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(j))           #index
               #feedback.pushInfo("l ---------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(l))           #item
               as_set = set(l)
               #feedback.pushInfo("as_set--------------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(as_set))
               inds = []               
               for k in outset.copy():
                   #feedback.pushInfo("hi inside outset.copy()")
                   #feedback.pushInfo(str(k))
                   #feedback.pushInfo(str(as_set))
                   if outlist[k] & as_set:
                       outset.remove(k)
                       as_set |= outlist[k]            #as_set= as_set|outlist[k] --> concatenate as_set and outlist in one object [{outlist[k]},{as_set}]
                       #feedback.pushInfo("as_set-----in if--------")
                       #eedback.pushInfo(str(as_set))
                       inds.extend(outinds[k])         #extend means --> take the value of outinds[k] and make inds equal this vlaue
               outset.add(j)                   #1st iteration outset = {0}
               #feedback.pushInfo("outset -----in iteration--------")   
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(outset))                              #outset in iteration
               outlist.append(as_set)          #1st iteration outlist = [{<QgsPointXY: POINT(77.50014668735001067 17.55122868859714913)>, <QgsPointXY: POINT(77.3797785331275918 17.55958329056117151)>}]
               #feedback.pushInfo("outlist -----in iteration--------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(outlist))                             #outlist in iteration
               outinds.append(inds + [j])      #1st iteration outinds = [[0]]
               #feedback.pushInfo("outinds -----in iteration--------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(outinds))                             #outinds in iteration
               #feedback.pushInfo("inds-----------in iteration------------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(inds))                                #inds in iteration
           #feedback.pushInfo("outset-----------------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(outset))                                   #outset
           #feedback.pushInfo("outlist-----------------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(outlist))                                  #outlist
           #feedback.pushInfo("outinds-----------------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(outinds))                                  #outinds
           
           outinds = [outinds[j] for j in outset]      
           set_list=[]
           for item in outset:
               set_list.append(item)
           list_points=[]
           for i in set_list:
               list_points.append(outlist[i])
           result_list_points=[]
           for k in list_points:
               item=[]
               for i in iter(k):
                   item.append(i)
               result_list_points.append(item)    
           result = [[selected_ids[j] for j in k] for k in outinds]  
           #feedback.pushInfo("result -----------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(result))
           return result

       # Compute the number of steps to display within the progress bar and
       # get features from source
       total = 100.0 / source.featureCount() if source.featureCount() else 0
       features = source.getFeatures()
       already_processed = []
       
       for current, feature in enumerate(features):
           # Stop the algorithm if cancel button has been clicked
           if feedback.isCanceled():
               break

           attrs = feature.attributes()
           geom = feature.geometry()
           #feedback.pushInfo("geom-----------------")
           #feedback.pushInfo(str(geom))
           curr_id = feature["id"]
           
           if curr_id not in already_processed:
               query = '"id" = %s' % (curr_id)
               selection = source.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterExpression(query))
               #feedback.pushInfo("filtered features with "+curr_id)
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(selection))
               selected_ids = []
               for feat in selection:
                   #feedback.pushInfo("feature----------------")
                   #feedback.pushInfo(str(feat))
                   for i in feat.geometry().asMultiPolyline():
                       #feedback.pushInfo(str(i))
                       selected_ids.append(i)
               #feedback.pushInfo("selected_ids----------------------------of "+curr_id)
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(selected_ids))
               #selected_ids = [k.geometry().asMultiPolyline() for k in selection]      #[repeat first term before 'for' with no of elements in selection ]
               #feedback.pushInfo("filtered features with "+curr_id)
               adjacent_feats = find_adjacent(selected_ids)
               #feedback.pushInfo("adjacent_feats------------------------")
               #feedback.pushInfo(str(adjacent_feats))
               for f in adjacent_feats:
                   first = True
                   
                   for x in range(0, len(f)):
                       geom = (QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([QgsPoint(w) for w in f[x]])) 
                       if first:
                           outFeat = QgsFeature()
                           outFeat.setGeometry(geom)
                           outGeom = outFeat.geometry()
                           first = False
                       else:
                           outGeom = outGeom.combine(geom)
                   outFeat.setAttributes(attrs)
                   outFeat.setGeometry(outGeom)
                   sink.addFeatures([outFeat])
               already_processed.append(curr_id)
           else:
               continue

       # Add the layer to the Layers panel
       return {self.OUTPUT: sink}
```